# Broadcasting multi-dimensional array indices of the same shape

Tags: numpy

I have a `mask` array which represents a 2-dimensional binary image. Let's say it's simply:

```py
mask = np.zeros((9, 9), dtype=np.uint8)
# 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# ------+-------+------
# 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# ------+-------+------
# 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
```

Suppose I want to flip the elements in the middle left [ninth](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/353764):

```py
# 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# ------+-------+------
# 1 1 1 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# 1 1 1 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# 1 1 1 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# ------+-------+------
# 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
```

My incorrect approach was something like this:

```py
x = np.arange(mask.shape[0])
y = np.arange(mask.shape[1])
mask[np.logical_and(y >= 3, y < 6), x < 3] = 1
# 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# ------+-------+------
# 1 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# 0 1 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# 0 0 1 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# ------+-------+------
# 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
# 0 0 0 | 0 0 0 | 0 0 0
```

(This is a simplification of the constraints I'm really dealing with, which would not be easily expressed as something like `mask[:3,3:6] = 1` as in this case. Consider the constraints arbitrary, like `x % 2 == 0 && y % 3 == 0` if you will.)

Numpy's behavior when the two index arrays are the same shape is to take them pairwise, which ends up only selecting the 3 elements above, rather than 9 I would like.

How would I update the right elements with constraints that apply to different axes? Given that the constraints are independent, can I do this by only evaluating my constraints N+M times, rather than N*M?

Comment: I can do something like `mask[np.logical_and(y >= 3, y < 6)[:,np.newaxis] * (x < 3)] = 1` but this doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: as fancy as it looks, the above is not much different from `mask[:3, 3:6]=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `broadcast` the boolean arrays, but you can construct the equivalent numeric indices with `ix_`:

```
In [330]: np.ix_((y>=3)&(y<6), x<3)                                             
Out[330]: 
(array([[3],
        [4],
        [5]]), array([[0, 1, 2]]))
```

Applying it:

```
In [331]: arr = np.zeros((9,9),int)                                             
In [332]: arr[_330] = 1                                                         
In [333]: arr                                                                   
Out[333]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Attempting to `broadcast` the booleans directly raises an error (`too many indices`):

```
arr[((y>=3)&(y<6))[:,None], x<3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Per your comment, let's try this fancier example:

```
mask = np.zeros((90,90), dtype=np.uint8)

# criteria
def f(x,y): return ((x-20)**2 < 50) & ((y-20)**2 < 50)

# ranges
x,y = np.arange(90), np.arange(90)

# meshgrid
xx,yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)

zz = f(xx,yy)

# mask
mask[zz] = 1
plt.imshow(mask, cnap='gray')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. In my "real" problem, the constraints are more complicated; the constraints could be something like `(y - 4)**2 < 25` which would index a parabolic* section of the mask. So it's not so much the specific shape I'm trying to make here, but the problem of having constraints on different axes.

Comment: fyi, `(y-4)**2<25` is not a circular shape. You probably want to update your example with what is closed to your real problem. I do think the solution is much similar to your given solution.

Comment: Thanks. I updated with another example and hopefully clarified. I guess the code becomes unreadable if I do it this way, though.

Comment: @rgov does the updated answer resemble your problem?

Comment: Let's say it was `(x - 20)**2 < 50` and `(y - 20)**2 < 50`, rather than a single constraint `(x-20)**2 + (y-20)**2 - 100 < 0`. How would that change your answer?

Comment: Thanks. I'll think about this solution. One downside is that it requires evaluating the constraints N*M times rather than N+M times, which should be possible given they are independent.